# In Clion with Bazel plugin, opening Drake project. Clangd put up some header files not found error

Tags: bazel, clion, drake

[Pic of Clion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrwmY.png)
[Pic of Hearder file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgfdf.png)

The [recommanded way](https://drake.mit.edu/clion.html) to open this project is Clion IDE with bazel plugin. I do so.
The project can be compiled with out any problem. In source files, the navigation works well, but it will jump to a cached header file. In that cached header file, navigation still works, but jump to other cached header files. In the real header file, things are geting wierd, a lot of red squiggles show up.

A cooresponding video is [here](https://youtu.be/vTxQIjsjSI8)

I am using CLion 2023.3.1 and 2023.11.23.0.1-api-version-233. I also checked https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/pull/5059 but still don't have a clue.

I really wonder HOW those Drake developers are working with this project. Hope some drake developers can share their workflow. Really Thanks!

Comment: I'm a Drake developer who uses Clion. Sadly I have the same problem with any new installations of Clion, while my older installations work fine. The problem does not go away if I install older versions of Clion on new machines, even though those versions work on older machines. I have not yet discovered a solution. Please let me know if you find one!

Comment: The statement "The recommended way to open this project is Clion IDE with bazel plugin" is incorrect.  Only a small fraction of Drake developers use CLion.

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri Thank you for your commment. I wonder how you are working with drake. I also submit an [issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20686) in github.

Comment: Some people use VSCode.  I use Emacs.  Others use vim.

Comment: @jwnimmer-tri wow  ∑(°口°๑)

Answer (score 1):

I use CLion with Drake source.  Thank you for the YouTube video. It explained the problems very well.  Like Sherm, I got the same problem.

These work around made my life easier:

1. Use Alt-1 to open Project tab, so I can browse and traverse the project tree.
2. Use Ctrl-Shift-N.  Type a partial file name to search. For example, to get to drake/geometry/geometry_frame.h, I can type "geo fra", CLion will give me a list of a few files matching that pattern that I can click to open.

In your video, you clicked on drake/examples/acrobot/gen/acrobot_params.h, which is special. The fact that it's under "gen" directory means it's not in the source tree.  It was auto-generated by this bazel rule:

```
drake_cc_vector_gen_library(
    name = "acrobot_params",
    srcs = ["acrobot_params_named_vector.yaml"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

In this special case, the generated file is in the bazel cache, so CLion did the right thing.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I think this problem is related with "strip_include_prefix" and "include_prefix" which confuse clangd to jump correctly. I also submit an [issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20686) in github.